# ASP.NET Web API HTTP 400 Bad Request

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Always get `400 Bad Request` on a valid request. Maybe some hints ? Need to fix this very badly.

**Controller**

```
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    public IEnumerable<string> GetAll(string language)
    {
        return new [] {"a", "b", "c"};
    }
}
```

**Request**

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:5378/Api/MyController/GetAll",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: { "language": language },
        cache: false,
        complete: function (xhr) {
            console.output(xhr.status.toString());
        }
    });
```

**WebApiConfig**

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );

    var appXmlType = config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.FirstOrDefault(t => t.MediaType == "application/xml");
    config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Remove(appXmlType);
}
```

**Webconfig**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DataConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-web-data;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\web-data.mdf" />
    <add name="AuthConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-web-auth;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\web-auth.mdf" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="true" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="SimpleRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="SimpleRoleProvider" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleRoleProvider, WebMatrix.WebData, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <membership defaultProvider="SimpleMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="SimpleMembershipProvider" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider, WebMatrix.WebData, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages.Razor" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
  </entityFramework>
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: An obvious problem is that you are POST'ing to a controller action that only supports GET. However, that should result in 405 Method Not Allowed. 400 Bad Request indicates that you are requesting a URL that has no route (e.g. no controller action can be matched to the URL).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Web api uses verbs to identify the action unless you configure it otherwise.

GetAll is not required in the url since web api will automatically find a method on your controller which starts with Get, when you use the GET http verb

Its easy to confuse the routing in asp .net MVC with web api.

**Request:**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:5378/Api/MyController",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: { "language": language },
    cache: false,
    complete: function (xhr) {
        console.output(xhr.status.toString());
    }
});
```

Comment: Incidentally, since you're posting the data, you need to name your method something which begins with Post, or use the AcceptVerbs attribute on the method

Answer (score 5):

Your controller class is called `MyController`.  Therefore your URL should be calling to `My` and not `MyController`.

```
type: "GET",
url: "http://localhost:5378/Api/My/"
```

Microsoft [provides some good information](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api) on understanding the routing conventions.

**Edit**: As Martin points out, if your method is a "Get" method, then your Ajax call shouldn't specify POST and it doesn't need to specify the `GetAll` because of the naming convention.